# Why isn't my scroll working?

Tags: jquery, html

My code checks if the scroll is `>=` to `100`. If true, it shows my sticky nav. If not, it *should* hide the sticky nav. Right now, the true portion works. But when I add the false argument, when I scroll, the entire sticky nav disappears in general.

**Code**

```
$(function(){
    var hasBeenTrigged = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100 && !hasBeenTrigged) { // if scroll is greater/equal then 100 and hasBeenTrigged is set to false.
            $("#sticky_nav").show();
            hasBeenTrigged = true;
        } else {
          $("#sticky_nav").hide();
        }



    });
});
```

Comment: You need to finish implementing `hasBeenTrigged`. Right now, on the first tick it will show the nav, then the second tick `!hasBeenTrigged` fails causing it to disappear.

Comment: if you scroll down 100px the sticky_nav shows up, but if you scroll back up and back down 'hasBeenTrigged' is still set to true, so it wont show up again. set 'hasBeenTrigged' to false when hiding it.

Comment: Why you are using (var hasBeenTrigged)

Comment: I added the following code: `else {
          hasBeenTrigged = false;
          $("#sticky_nav").hide();
        }` When I don't scroll, the sticky nav is hidden. When I do, the nav flashes hidden and visible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the variable hasBeenTrigged in the true part of `$(this).scrollTop() >= 100` statement

```
$(function(){
    var hasBeenTrigged = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100) { // if scroll is greater/equal then 100 and hasBeenTrigged is set to false.
           if(!hasBeenTrigged){
              $("#sticky_nav").show();
              hasBeenTrigged = true;
           }
        } else {
          // this only if you want to show again, on the next scroll down
          hasBeenTrigged = false;
          $("#sticky_nav").hide();
        }



    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to check scrollTop only so you should remove hasBeenTrigged from the if condition

```
$(function(){
    var hasBeenTrigged = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100) { // if scroll is greater/equal then 100 and hasBeenTrigged is set to false.
            $("#sticky_nav").show();
            hasBeenTrigged = true;
        } else {
          $("#sticky_nav").hide();
        }



    });
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69Lxw8zt/